# JavaScript Help Checking Passwords Match

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code that works on this site: http://jsfiddle.net/FPNBe/2/

However, the exact code doesn't work on my site.  (With the exception I had to add

`<script TYPE="text/javascript"> & < /script>` around the javascript.)

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: If you have firebug, check if you loaded jquery.  Are you calling $(document).ready(function() {  });  with your script inside the function block

Comment: Yes < script src="js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"> is loaded before

Comment: @Nikki: You can show code by wrapping it in back ticks `

Comment: @Nikki, are you doing as Alex R pointed below.  Calling it within document ready?

Comment: As a side note, jquery 1.6.1 is out, I noticed you are referencing 1.3.2 which is not the problem,but you probably can upgrade

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the script inside `$(document).ready()`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#password, #confirmpassword').keyup(function() { checkPass(); } );
});
```

Comment: Don't worry, everyone makes mistakes.

Answer (score 2):

This line:

```
$('#password, #confirmpassword').keyup(function() { checkPass(); } );
```

Must only be executed after the elements in question have been added to the DOM (Document Object Model) by the browser, so that jQuery can find them. To [wait until the DOM is ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/), meaning that all the page's elements are accessible, you can put this line inside a function, which you can pass to jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#password, #confirmpassword').keyup(function() { checkPass(); } );
});
```

Or a bit shorter:

```
$(function() {
    $('#password, #confirmpassword').keyup(function() { checkPass(); } );
});
```